# Magento 2 with UIkit 3 implementation

Tags: magento2, theme, frontend

I'm trying to create a theme with [the UIkit 3 framework](http://getuikit.com). I've added the `uikit.min.js` and `uikit-icons.min.js` files (and CSS as well), but when I try to add a modal to the page, it doesn't work.

It looks like UIkit cannot initialize the modal (or any other component).

Has somebody already implemented UIkit 3 in a Magento 2 custom theme? Is it possible to help me?

Comment: Have you loaded the JS via Require or via XML?

Comment: I've added it through XML ([theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml).

Comment: I think this may be the problem, you should be adding JS via require and setting UiKit3 as a dependency. You can then add the dependency to other scripts.

Comment: How can i implement it with requireJS? I'm not so familiar with requireJS and Magento 2. And is see a lot of different "tutorials" on internet.

Comment: I don't have time to provide a good answer at the moment sorry, if I get time I'll provide an answer. The official docs might help - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html

Answer (score 1):

try to copy this code inside your template

require(["uikit"], function(){});